# Better way to write this jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a better way to write this so that I'm not "re-selecting" #abc?

```
    $('#abc').click( function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#abc').addClass('someclass');
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm new to jQuery but try the following:

```
$(this).addClass('someclass');
```

`this` refers to the element that the callback is being called for.

Comment: I'm new too.  Works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#abc').click( function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).addClass('someclass');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var abc = $('#abc');
abc.click( function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    abc.addClass('someclass');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `this` from within your callback.

```
$(this).addClass("someclass");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this -

```
$('#abc').click( function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).addClass('someclass');
    });
```

Check this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eypwC/).